# How to debug this error having to do with Queues simulating a customer line?

Tags: java

So I'm given a list of customers and their arrival times, and I add them to a queue. My program is set up so that if a customer arrives, he/she is taken off the queue and put on to a second queue, and then a bunch of other stuff happens.

The employee serving time is a constant 5 minutes or 300 seconds, and the store closes at 5pm. So if someone comes in at 4:56 and no one else is on line, that person will get served and be done with even though the store closes at 5. Other customers who might arrive after him though won't get served, even if they come before 5.

So the problem is, the important parts of my code only run if the first queue isn't empty. But from the list of customers I've given, a guy comes in at 4:56pm, then another two people come in at 4:58 and 4:59 respectively, and with so at 4:59 that first queue is empty, and my important blocks of code no longer run.

Just gonna leave the relevant parts of my code.

```
if (eventqueue.isEmpty() == false) {
    if (eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs == clock) {
        if (customerqueue.isEmpty() == true)
            eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = 0;
        customerqueue.enqueue(eventqueue.dequeue());

    // does stuff
    }
}
```

So that first if loop needs to evaluate to be true if the parts of my code where I'm evaluating customers and what not can run, but when that last guy is taken off the queue, this part no longer runs. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from the snippet provided, but it sounds like you need a boolean flags like `servedLateCustomer`. Initially it is false. Once you serve someone after 4:55 you set it `true`. Then you use that flag as part of your condition (don't queue up work if you've already served one late customer).

One "thought for the future" could be make it an int counter `lateCustomersServed` so you can tweek the conditional to allow one or more late comers to be handled instead of just "0 or 1"

Comment: I get what you mean but I'm not sure how to write this. What would you recommend? https://hastebin.com/awopafitug.vbs